# Scala use dependent type in type signature of function?

Tags: scala

I'm not sure if the phrasing of the question title was appropriate, so I'll elaborate.

```
sealed trait RedisKey[A] {
  type valueType = A
  def name: String
}
case object FirstName extends RedisKey[String] { val name = "first_name" }
case object Age extends RedisKey[Int] { val name = "age" }

trait Redis {
  def fetch(key: RedisKey)// : key.valueType
}
```

I need to constrain the return type of `fetch` by `RedisKey`'s **dependent type** `valueType` (not sure if this is the right term). But obviously, the above wont work since I need a concrete instance of `RedisKey` before I can access its dependent type.

Is it possible to achieve this in any way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with dependent type too:

```
sealed trait RedisKey {
  type valueType
  def name: String
}
case object FirstName extends RedisKey { type valueType = String; val name = "first_name" }
case object Age extends RedisKey { type valueType = Int;  val name = "age" }

trait Redis {
  def fetch(key: RedisKey): key.valueType
}
(null: Redis).fetch(Age): Int
(null: Redis).fetch(FirstName): String
```

The last two lines are there to test return type of the method in the repl.

Comment: HUH? we can refer to an instance in signature? I've confirmed that this works but how? Is this because of the presence of dependent type in `trait` that allows this? Could you refer me to a formal spec for this?

Comment: The `RedisKey` trait contains a abstract type member (`valueType`). The `fetch` method uses singleton types in its return type ([spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#singleton-types)).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out after about 5 minutes after posting this question, I realized I was overthinking this.

The following works without dependent type hackery.

```
sealed trait RedisKey[A] {
  def name: String
}
case object FirstName extends RedisKey[String] { val name = "first_name" }
case object Age extends RedisKey[Int] { val name = "age" }

trait Redis {
  def fetch[A](key: RedisKey[A]): A
}
```